# Store object of a class as value of HashMap inside a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to integer values as keys and another integer as values inside nested loop. For example:
1 has value 30,
2 has value 31,
3 has value 32
and so on.

I tried to run loop inside loop, like this

```
package exampl;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i < 20; i++){
            for (int j=30; j < 50; j++) {
                map.put(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But end up getting HashMap like:
1 has value 49,
2 has value 49
and so on

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a nested loop, simple add `29` to your `i` value

```
for (int i=1; i < 20; i++){
       map.put(i, i + 29);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply,  but I am trying to achieve something else. That was just an example.I am actually trying to store all the dates from January 1st 2021 to December 31 2030 as values of HashMap.

Comment: You should show what you are really trying to do.  But anyway in your code, every time that you do `map.put(i, j);` you are replacing the value for `i` with `j` so that is why the last value `49` is remaining.  Read the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V) - it says *Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.*